# using to_tsvector and to_tsquery to filter non roman characters

Tags: string, postgresql, search, normalization

I want to allow multilingual search support for my app.

[Postgresql 9.6 Search Controls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-controls.html) says I need `tsvector` and `tsquery` to properly parse/normalize text. This works fine with roman-based languages, but not non-roman characters.

Considering this search snippet

```
where to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('hola')
```

I am looking for a title with "hola mi amiga", and it is found. However, given:

```
where to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('你') //language = Chinese, Code = zh-CN
```

I am looking for a title with `你好嗎` and it is **not** found.

What considerations should I take to allow string normalization to work with non roman characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the configuration right

> **default_text_search_config (string)**
> Selects the text search configuration that is used by those variants of the text search functions that do not have an explicit argument specifying the configuration. See Chapter 12 for further information. The built-in default is pg_catalog.simple, but initdb will initialize the configuration file with a setting that corresponds to the chosen lc_ctype locale, if a configuration matching that locale can be identified.

You can see the current value with

```
SHOW default_text_search_config;
or SELECT get_current_ts_config();
```

You can change it for the session with `SET default_text_search_config = newconfiguration;` Or, you can use `ALTER DATABASE <db> SET default_text_search_config = newconfiguration`

[From Chapter 12. Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS)

> During installation an appropriate configuration is selected and default_text_search_config is set accordingly in postgresql.conf. If you are using the same text search configuration for the entire cluster you can use the value in postgresql.conf. To use different configurations throughout the cluster but the same configuration within any one database, use **ALTER DATABASE ... SET. Otherwise, you can set default_text_search_config in each session.**
>
> **Each text search function that depends on a configuration has an optional regconfig argument**, so that the configuration to use can be specified explicitly. default_text_search_config is used only when this argument is omitted.

You can use `\dF` to see the text search configurations you have installed.

So what you want, is something like this

```
where to_tsvector('newconfig', title) @@ to_tsquery('newconfig', '你')
```

No idea what language the query is in to answer this question, or what configuration will properly stem that language.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for that language. You'll have to research text search configuration options if there is anything that can be done. My assumption is the benefits won't be like they are in English. AFAIK, in Chinese one unicode-code-point for the grapheme and you've communicated the entire lexeme. FTS is kind of based on exploiting a difference. But, I've never worked with Chinese.

Comment: can you explain a bit further, specifically "in Chinese one unicode-code-point for the grapheme and you've communicated the entire lexeme. FTS is kind of based on exploiting a difference"? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the idea behind FTS is that you store and index a vector of words rather than just a string of characters. Doing so is more efficient. If there is no concept of "character" what are you doing? (I'm sure you've got some advantages -- I just don't know enough about them).  If you have the word "Engineering" it takes a lot characters. Searching for other cases of it is a complex task. If you collapse it to a single node finding it becomes much easier. In Chinese, they're naturally collapsed afaik 你 has a meaning and can not be simplified further (for the purposes of search).

Comment: Chris I'm having issues with Chinese Full Text Search extension `ZHParser`, running the query `select title from knowledgebase_topics where to_tsvector('testzhcfg',title) @@ to_tsquery('testzhcfg','说话'); ` gets me error `text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored` even though my Chinese text contains lexemes - "说话" means speak. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659909/fts-non-latin-text-search-query-contains-only-stop-words-or-doesnt-contain-lex)